# EMF Induced in a Conductor Rotating in A Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-induction

Can you help me visualize and understand this question as to why the answer is A?

I know that the field lines should cut through and sin of the angle between the magnetic field and the motion of the conductor shouldn't be zero in order to induce emf.

However, the longer side of the conductor cuts through the field so why is the emf induced zero still across X and Y? We have a 90-degree angle for the longer side. Am I wrong? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the surface enclosed, and the normal vector to that surface.

$\vec{B} \cdot \vec{da} = |\vec{B}| |\vec{da}| cos(\theta)$

The vector $\vec{da}$ is always perpendicular to $\vec{B}$

ie  $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$

$cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 0$

Hence the emf is 0